# validate that if it already exists to skip the creation from scratch and just attach the instance profile to EC2 and execute the remaining code?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have written the terraform module with EC2 instance creation and for EC2 login I have added an instance profile with SSM IAM role creation and policy attachment in the same file.

while re-deploying the code in another region using the modules including the EC2 module I'm facing the below error.

ERROR:
dev-ssm-role already exist

Is there any way it can validate that if it already exists to skip the creation from scratch and just attach the instance profile to EC2 and execute the remaining code?

need help, how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: Since IAM is a global service, the fact you are doing something in a different region does not matter. However, if the IAM role is already there, you could use a [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role) to fetch the existing role and attach it to an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different states, you should import the existing resources. You can find an import example in the documentation of your resource on the bottom. For EC2 the ID would be sufficient (see [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.3.0/docs/resources/instance#import)).